# Custom serilization of a complex C# object using simple objects

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using a utility class from QuickGraph called `AdjacencyGraph` that has a complex internal structure.

I do not care for all the internal properties of the complex class and I cant change it as its from a nuget package - at most in my database I am just concerned in storing an array of Dependency objects that can be used to reconstruct the AdacencyGraph:

```
public class Dependency
{
    public Dependency(string source, string target)
    {
        this.Source = source;
        this.Target = target;
    }

    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Target { get; set; }
}
```

On serialization, all i need to do is the following code:

```
void Serialize(Dependencies toSerialize)
{
    var toBeStored = toSerialize.GetAllDependencies();
    // write this to mongodb somehow
}
```

And deserialization build the Dependencies object:

```
Dependencies Deserialize(IEnumerable<Dependency> hydrateFrom)
{
    var dependencies = new Dependencies();

    foreach(var d in hydrateFrom)
    {
        dependencies.SetRequiresFor(d.Source, d.Target);
    }
}
```

**Question**

How would I go about intercepting the serialization process and output?

***Other Information***

I have wrapped the AdjacencyGraph around in a class that lists all Dependency objects, and can accept a list of Dependency objects too.

```
class Dependencies
{
    private AdjacencyGraph<string, Edge<string>> relationshipGraph = new AdjacencyGraph<string, Edge<string>>();

    public void SetRequiresFor(SkuId on, SkuId requires)
    {
        var toAdd = new Edge<string>(on.Value, requires.Value);
        this.relationshipGraph.AddVerticesAndEdge(toAdd);

    }

    public IEnumerable<Dependency> GetAllDependencies()
    {
        foreach(var edge in this.relationshipGraph.Edges)
        {
            yield return new Dependency(edge.Source, edge.Target);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 things you need to do:

1. Implement a `BsonSerializer`.
2. Implement a `BsonSerializationProvider` that will point `Dependencies` to your serializer.<sup>*</sup>
3. Register the provider in your application's initialization.

### BsonSerializer

```
public class DependenciesBsonSerializer : BsonBaseSerializer
{
    public override void Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        // implement using bsonWriter
    }

    public override object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        // implement using bsonReader
    }
}
```

### BsonSerializationProvider

```
public sealed class BsonSerializationProvider : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    public IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(Dependncies)
        {
            return new DependenciesBsonSerializer ();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

### Registeration

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new BsonSerializationProvider());
```

---

<sup>* You *could* cut the provider and register the serializer directly using `BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer` but I still recommend grouping all your serializers in a single provider.</sup>